# How to compare Gwet's ac1 coefficient between group of raters?

Tags: r, reliability, agreement-statistics

So I have 4 raters who scored the subjects in the study with a nominal score like: "Present", "maybe", and "absent". I made pairs of the raters and evaluated their inter-rater reliability using Gwet's ac1 coefficient. The pairs were:

1. Rater A and B
2. Rater A and C
3. Rater A and D
4. Rater B and C
5. Rater B and D
6. Rater C and D

I was wondering if I there is a way I could compare the Gwet's AC1 coefficient from these pairs and see if they were statistically different?

Comment: Note to close-voters: I do not understand why this should be closed as "programming". Voted to leave open. (It *may* be "unclear"; I don't know anything about the topic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the following article from Gwet herself: https://agreestat.com/papers/correlated_agreement_coefficients_educational_and_psychological_measurement_2016.pdf? This might be useful.

Just to make sure, your goal is not to know if the 4 raters overall have different ratings or not, right? Otherwise you could just use Gwet's AC1 for more than 2 raters to see if they are all different or at least one isn't.

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was looking for. Do you know if there is a R code for this? and yes I wanted to compare the pairs amongst each other.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not aware of any R code of this at the moment, my best advice at the moment would be to just to program step-by-step yourself so you really understand it immediately as well.

Comment: @Kierrajames If this answer meets your needs, could you accept it by clicking the check mark? Thanks